# Определить тип данных

Tags: php, javascript, phpmyadmin

Есть сайт с генератором кода. Столкнулся с такой проблемой: какой тип данных у кода, который выдается пользователю. Не знаю, как записать в `phpmyadmin`.

Пример кода: `Xrsoai4hyFK9zEy`.

Comment: varchar(16), скажем...

Answer (score 2):

Выбор типа данных для хранения в БД (в данном случае MySQL) зависит от характеристик этих самых данных. В вашем примере представлена строка символов. Если она всегда будет меньше 255 символов, то прекрасно подойдет varchar. Для бОльшего количества - тип text. По ссылке представлена хорошая статья, которая позволит определиться с выбором: [https://ruhighload.com/Выбор+типов+данных+в+mysql](https://ruhighload.com/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80+%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2+%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85+%D0%B2+mysql)